# How can I set a specific date into a Joda Time DateTime object?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I am pretty new in **Joda Time** and I have the following doubt:

I have simply created a new empty `DateTime` object, in this way:

```
DateTime dataMovimentoFittizio = new DateTime();
```

My problem is that is seems to me that then I can't set the year, month and day for this object.

How can I correctly set a specific date into this object?

Comment: There are many other constructors available for `DateTime` besides `DateTime()`. Have you looked at the [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)?

Comment: @GriffeyDog I know the constructor, but can't I set it afert having construct the object?

Comment: No, `DateTime` objects are immutable.

Comment: From the start of the documentation: "DateTime is the standard implementation of an unmodifiable datetime class." So no, you can't. But there are plenty of "withYear", "withDate" etc methods which create new instances based on an existing one and one difference.

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you should use JSR-310, available in the `java.time` package.

Answer (score 1):

## Immutable objects

The Joda-Time classes mostly use [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), designed to not be changed after instantiation.

Use methods to instantiate new objects based partially on the values in the existing object.

## java.time

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, and advises migrating to the java.time classes.

The java.time classes strictly use [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

### `LocalDate`

For a date-only value without time of day and without time zone. Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 23 );  // January 23, 2016
```